# Ruby 2D array transpose - variables not working as expected

Tags: ruby, arrays, scope, transpose

Hi I am a Ruby newbie and could use some help with the code below.

This is supposed to transpose  a 2d array.  First, I know that using `my_array.transpose` will accomplish the same thing as this entire method.  This is a learning exercise for me, which is working seeing as I don't know why my code is doing what its doing.

Again, this should transpose a 2d array. What it's actually doing is creating an array with the correct number of nested arrays (rows), but they are all empty.

Also my method appears to be changing the value of `my_array` which I don't want it to do.  It looks like something is going wrong with my variables, I've tested the code and `new_row` does contain the correct expected values as it goes through its loop - but somehow when I call `new_row.clear` its also wiping the values inside `new_array`.

Edit - to clarify what I mean by transpose, given the array in the code below, the transposed array should be:
    [
    [0,4,8]
    [1,5,9]
    [2,6,10]
    [3,7,11]
    ]

```
def my_transpose(inital_array)
  new_row = []
  new_array = []
  new_row_start = 0
  indexer = 0

  row_count = inital_array.count
  inital_array.flatten!
  col_count = inital_array.count / row_count

  col_count.times do 
    row_count.times do 
      new_row<<inital_array[indexer]
      indexer += col_count
    end
    new_array<<new_row
    new_row_start += 1
    indexer = new_row_start
    new_row.clear
  end
  return new_array
end

my_array = [
  [0,1,2,3],
  [4,5,6,7],
  [8,9,10,11]
]
new_array = my_transpose(my_array)
print "old array:"
print my_array.inspect
puts
print "new array:"
puts new_array.inspect
```

Comment: What do you mean by transposing an array?

Comment: existing rows in the initial array should correspond to the columns in the new array and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most objects in Ruby are stored by reference - arrays included. What's happening in your case is you are appending `new_row` to `new_array` which correctly stores the row value. Then later, you are clearing `new_row`. Since `new_array` has a reference to that same object, the row is also cleared in `new_array`.

Use `dup` to create a new array object when you add it to `new_array`:

```
new_array << new_row.dup
```

The same behavior is occurring when you call `initial_array.flatten!`. The `flatten!` method modifies the receiver and updates the same array referenced by `my_array` outside of the function.

Comment: Thank you, that worked, I figured it was something along those lines but did not know about `dup`.

Comment: Take a look at Ismael's answer too. He also has some good points.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with clear. You are clearing the same array you just created. So you are loosing your work.

What you want instead of clear is actually create a new array with:

```
new_row = []
```

About why your are changing the my_array is because you are using a bang method. the `flatten!`. All methods that end with a `!` most of the times are mutable methods. That said, they change the object you are calling it on. So you need to be careful when you use them.

Here is a work around. Just assign the result of a normal `flatten` that returns a new object.

```
inital_array = inital_array.flatten
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured out that part of the problem after reading the other answer above.  Seeing how using new_row = [] in this case achieves the same result as using `dup` and `clear` also illuminates the way the references are working. Much appreciated!